# Conditional use of RequestDispatcher to send the same Java object across multiple JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, requestdispatcher

Please bear with me as I'm very new to JSP. I thank you in advance for your help; I greatly appreciate it.

**BACKGROUND**

I am trying to build a web application which "remembers" certain java objects throughout a user's login session. Currently, I have a servlet which uses RequestDispatcher to send an object to a JSP page via its doPost method.

Here is the doPost of the servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {

    String strBook = "Test Book";

    // Send strBook to the next jsp page for rendering
    request.setAttribute("book", strBook);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("sample.jsp");
    dispatcher.include(request, response);

}
```

The sample.jsp gets the strBook object, and processes it. The body of the sample.jsp looks like this:

```
<body>

<% 
    // Obtain strBook for rendering on current page
    String strBook = (String) request.getAttribute("book"); 

    /*
      // TODO: A way to conditionally call code below, when form is submitted 
      // in order for sample2.jsp to have strBook object.

      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("sample2.jsp");
      dispatcher.include(request, response);
    */

%>


<h1> Book: </h1>
<p> <%=strBook%> </p>

<form action="sample2.jsp"  method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="buttonSubmit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Buy"/>
</form>

</body>
```

**PROBLEM**

How do I take the strBook object from within sample.jsp, and send it to the sample2.jsp ***WHEN the submit button is clicked*** (so the strBook object can be utilized in sample2.jsp)?

Currently, the body of sample2.jsp looks like this, and the strBook within is null:

```
<body>

<% 
    // Obtain strBook for rendering on current page
    String strBook = (String) request.getAttribute("book"); 
%>


<h1> Book: </h1>
<p> <%="SAMPLE 2 RESULT " + strBook%> </p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass it as parameter to next jsp.

Sample1.jsp

```
<form action="sample2.jsp"  method="post">
   <input type="submit" id="buttonSubmit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Buy"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="book" value="<%=strBook%>"/>
</form>
```

Sample2.jsp

```
 <% 
// Obtain strBook for rendering on current page
String strBook = (String) request.getParameter("book"); 
 %>


<h1> Book: </h1>
<p> <%="SAMPLE 2 RESULT " + strBook%> </p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Sas - I appreciate it. In my real application the strBook is actually a more complex object (a "Book" object not a String), so in sample1.jsp the code, value="<%=strBook%>", would be unable to transport the Book object. I was just looking for a more general means to sending any kind of object from jsp to servlet and vice versa, and I think I just found a way using the "sessions" feature.